# Where does "auth" come from

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-middleware

I'm currently learning Lumen, I'm running a fresh install of Laravel 6.x .
I'm using RESTClient to stimulate my Lumen API/send http-Requests.

I want to set up some basic authentication with JWT now, and I already accomplished this. 
I get a valid JWT and when I pass it through the following code, the firebase middleware (5.x) accepts the token, if valid, and rejects it if invalid.
The code doing the validation resides inside my `AuthServiceProvider.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


//new Code
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

     public function boot()
     {
       // Here you may define how you wish users to be authenticated for your Lumen
       // application. The callback which receives the incoming request instance
       // should return either a User instance or null. You're free to obtain
       // the User instance via an API token or any other method necessary.

       $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
         $key = 'pawifjopawiejfpoaiwejfpoji';
         $jwt = preg_replace('/^Bearer (.*)/', '$1', $request->header('Authorization'));
         $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, ['HS256']);

         //return User::where('email', $decoded->email)->first();
         return "Hello From Auth!";
       });
     }
}
```

The router calling the middleware and routing its result to the controller resides in web.php and looks like this:

```
$router->get('myStorage', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'AuthController@myStorage']);
```

Now, my problem is this:
I've looked into all the depenencies inside providers/AuthServiceProvider.php, ServiceProvider.php insinde vendor/Illuminate/Support, Authenticate.php inside app/http/middleware and also bootstrap/app.php where the registering takes place.
The "auth" key/denominator, as it appears multiple times inside the sourcecode and also references the authentication middleware during routing, remains a mystery to me. 
I don't know what object it points to.

I've tested changing it to "auth2" in all the places I found it (see above), but then I get this exception thrown by Lumen:

```
(2/2) BindingResolutionException

Target class [auth2] does not exist.
```

So somewhere, this class must have been defined.
Inside Authenticate.php, there is this line in the head of the code

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;
```

And I've manipulated it, alongside its occurrences in the whole code of authenticate.php .
But I always get the same error.

I want to know where this "auth" is coming from, because I also want to employ a middleware for AUTHORIZATION, following the AUTHENTICATION. 
The routes would then look kinda like this:

```
$router->get('myStorage', ['middleware' => ['authenticate', 'authorize'], 'uses' => 'AuthController@myStorage']);
```

To do this, I think I need a better understanding of how and where this (third-party) middleware/its components are defined. Otherwise I will probably run into issues when registering this stuff for example.

Comment: its a binding on the container ... https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/facades#facade-class-reference ... `auth` in regards to middleware is a short name assigned to the `Authenticate` middleware in `bootstrap/app.php` ... here is the binding lumen is doing for 'auth' on the container https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/6.x/src/Application.php#L275

Comment: Hi,in Laravel please check protected $routeMiddleware in App\Http\Kernel.php here where its defined auth middleware for Laravel app

Comment: @MilenaSchmidt that doesn't exist in Lumen, it is registered differently

Comment: @lagbox Thanks for information. Question is tagged Laravel so I also add this infromation in case OP would also try laravel some day

Comment: @lagbox thanks this has already helped a lot!
About the Application::loadComponent() (see here: https://hotexamples.com/examples/laravel.lumen/Application/loadComponent/php-application-loadcomponent-method-examples.html ) 

What does the first argument, $config, do? I can see in the registerAuthBindings that the auth keyword goes in there, but what does this actually do? Is there a list of keywords for this parameter, like 'auth', 'guard' etc.? Can one view a documentation for this? Furthermore, as far as I understand Loadcomponent only returns itself?